# How to restrict access for different users?

Tags: profile, customsetting

Let's say, I am having 4 users : User1, User2, User3 and User4.
All Users assigned with Same Profile. The Profile which is assigned to them having all access - Create, Read, Edit and Delete. But User1 should have all access, User2 should have Read, Edit and Create, User3 should have Read, Edit and User4 should have only Read access. How to achieve this? Where am I lagging?

Comment: Please read about permission set https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ghbf0jYyQY

Comment: Permission set is like giving additional permission to the users. In this scenario will it be meaningful?

Comment: @user51009 using permission set you can't restrict but you can do it other way around. Restrict everything at profile level and then extend permission using permission set.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions in Salesforce are additive. This means that it is not possible to remove permissions by assigning permission sets (N.B. there are a few "permissions" that actually do restrict access, but those are rare; "API Only User", for example, actually restricts logins from the UI). Instead, you will start by modifying the profile so it has only Read permission, then create three permission sets (one with Edit, one with Create and Edit, and one with full access), and assign them to the users appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Permission set is the key to achieve this.

You have mentioned about 4 users with same profile.

In the profile please remove the Create , Read , Edit , Delete Permission.

Create one permission set lets say Permission Set 1 and give all access to the object in that permission set , assign it to user 1.

Similarly for user2 create a permission set say Permission Set 2 which have Read , Edit and Create access for the object.

Like this you have to follow and create two more permission sets and assign to user 3 and user 4.

I hope this make sense and solves your problem.